# Data is not uploading to firebase database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Aposts is name of my table in firebase and i have declared all the objects and typecasted them as required i have used an array to take values and upload it.
When i debug i get InputConnectionWrapper issue, and data does not get uploaded.

It gives me toast message as added but when i check in my databse in firebase it is not uploaded.

How to resolve this?

```
//to add a new post to database
     public class Advpost extends Activity {
Button advbtn;
EditText jobtitle;
EditText jobdescription;
EditText city;
EditText phonenumber;
EditText pay;
EditText emailid;
EditText completiondate;

DatabaseReference posts;


@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.advpost);

    posts = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Aposts");
    advbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.advbtn);
    jobtitle = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.jobtitle);
    jobdescription = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.jobdescription);
    city = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.city);
    phonenumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.phonenumber);
    pay = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pay);
    emailid = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.emailid);
    completiondate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.completiondate);
    advbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            addAposts();
        }
    });
}

private void addAposts() {

String title = jobtitle.getText().toString().trim();
String description = jobdescription.getText().toString().trim();
String cityname = city.getText().toString().trim();
String phno = phonenumber.getText().toString().trim();
String Amt = pay.getText().toString().trim();
String mailid = emailid.getText().toString().trim();
String duedate = completiondate.getText().toString().trim();


if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(title)) {
    String id = posts.push().getKey();
    Aposts Aposts = new Aposts();
    posts.child(id).setValue(Aposts);
    Toast.makeText(this, "Added", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
} else {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

---

```
public class Aposts {
private String title;
private String description;
private String cityname;
private String phno;
private String amt;
private String mailid;
private String duedate;

public Aposts() {
    this.title = title;
    this.description = description;
    this.cityname = cityname;
    this.phno = phno;
    this.amt = amt;
    this.mailid = mailid;
    this.duedate = duedate;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

public String getCityname() {
    return cityname;
}

public void setCityname(String cityname) {
    this.cityname = cityname;
}

public String getPhno() {
    return phno;
}

public void setPhno(String phno) {
    this.phno = phno;
}

public String getAmt() {
    return amt;
}

public void setAmt(String amt) {
    this.amt = amt;
}

public String getMailid() {
    return mailid;
}

public void setMailid(String mailid) {
    this.mailid = mailid;
}

public String getDuedate() {
    return duedate;
}

public void setDuedate(String duedate) {
    this.duedate = duedate;
}
```

}

Comment: Hi, I don't see in your code where you're setting the data in your database, you're just reading it. Is this the complete code?

Comment: Please post the complete code, including the part where you are adding data to the database. Also, you have written the comment 'to add a new post to database' while in the code beneath it, you are reading the database not writing to it.

Comment: Sorry guys i have now updated the code i have uploaded wrong code by mistake..

Comment: can you show Aposts class?

Comment: public class Aposts
{
    private String title;
    private String description;
    private String cityname;
    private String phno;
    private String amt;
    private String mailid;
    private String duedate;     //it will also have constructor get and set methods in it.

Comment: Please add the entire code so we can help you.

Comment: What's even better than adding more code, is trying to reproduce the problem with less code. For example: can you reproduce the problem without the `Aposts` class? If so, that rules out that the problem is in that class. If you really can't reproduce it without that class, can you reproduce it with a smaller `Aposts` class with fewer fields? Trying this may point you to the field that is causing the problem for example. Doing this iteratively will either help you find the cause of the problem yourself, or it will give you a so-called [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for sharing.

Comment: Refer this example https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#updating_or_deleting_data